# Bash - Convert escape character colored text to BBCode

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, escape-characters, replace

I want to convert a `terminal escape-character colored text file` to `BBCode` colored text.
For this i've created an Android logfile with `logcat -Cd > /sdcard/logcat.txt`. The `-C` switch adds the color escape characters. The output looks like this:

```
[0m[38;5;231mV/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 55 to /dev/null
[0m[38;5;231mV/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
[0m[38;5;40mI/ggheart ( 1111): onStop
[0m[38;5;40mI/Test    ( 1111): onStop
[0m[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): handleBindApplication:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad
[0m[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
[0m[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
```

To convert the color codes to `BBCode` i've written this `sed` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Use 'logcat -Cd > /sdcard/logcat.txt' as input file

sed '/\x1b/ {
    s/\x1b\[0m\x1b\[38;5;40m/\[COLOR="Green"\]/
    s/\x1b\[0m\x1b\[38;5;196m/\[COLOR="Red"\]/
    s/\x1b\[0m\x1b\[38;5;75m/\[COLOR="Blue"\]/
    s/\x1b\[0m\x1b\[38;5;166m/\[COLOR="Sienna"\]/
    s/\x1b\[0m\x1b\[38;5;231m/\[COLOR="DarkSlateGray"\]/
    s/\x1b\[38;5;40m/\[COLOR="Green"\]/
    s/\x1b\[38;5;196m/\[COLOR="Red"\]/
    s/\x1b\[38;5;75m/\[COLOR="Blue"\]/
    s/\x1b\[38;5;166m/\[COLOR="Sienna"\]/
    s/\x1b\[38;5;231m/\[COLOR="DarkSlateGray"\]/
    s/\x1b\[0m/\[COLOR="Black"\]/
    s/$/\[\/COLOR\]/
    }' <logcat.txt >logcat2.txt
```

The processed output text looks like this:

```
[COLOR="DarkSlateGray"]V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 55 to /dev/null[/COLOR]
[COLOR="DarkSlateGray"]V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Green"]I/ggheart ( 1111): onStop[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Green"]I/Test    ( 1111): onStop[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Blue"]D/ActivityThread( 4666): handleBindApplication:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Blue"]D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Blue"]D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152[/COLOR]
```

This is syntactically correct and works properly in corresponding forum boards but its not optimized and wastes too many characters (that are limited in most boards) due to `COLOR` tags not spanning over multiple lines.

It should rather look like this where same colored lines do not close/reopen the same `COLOR` tag:

```
[COLOR="DarkSlateGray"]V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 55 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Green"]I/ggheart ( 1111): onStop
I/Test    ( 1111): onStop[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Blue"]D/ActivityThread( 4666): handleBindApplication:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad
D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152[/COLOR]
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Is it even possible with line based text processor? Its not mandatory as long as it runs on shell/bash/cygwin.

Comment: Possible, but difficult, using `sed`. Easy using `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Noting a comment about "Easy using awk", that would be relative to sed.

OP was describing a not-very-well documented feature of `logcat` (see [commit](https://gitlab.com/pbeeler/system_core/commit/62fb4b13c721799e6d66fb267cf8096b4d73ee49)) which tells `logcat` to assign hardcoded-colors to each line based on the log entry's *priority*.

There are other choices, such as [logcat-color](https://github.com/marshall/logcat-color), [PID cat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) and [coloredlogcat](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/) which let you color different *fields*, e.g., raising the possibility of multiple colors per line.

Here's an awk script which recognizes the hardcoded logcat colors, but allows multiple colors per line:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        colors["0"]        = "Black";
        colors["38;5;40"]  = "Green";
        colors["38;5;196"] = "Red";
        colors["38;5;75"]  = "Blue";
        colors["38;5;166"] = "Sienna";
        colors["38;5;231"] = "DarkSlateGray";
        color = "";
        last = "";
        this = "";
        save = "";
}
/\033/ {
        done = "";
        while ( $0 ~ /\033\[[;0-9]*m/ ) {
                mark = match($0, /\033\[[;0-9]*m/ );
                if ( mark > 1 ) { done = done substr($0, 1, mark - 1); }
                item = substr($0, RSTART + 2, RLENGTH - 3);
                $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
                if ( match($0, /^\033\[[;0-9]*m/ ) > 0 ) continue;
                color = colors[item];
                if ( done == "" ) this = color;
                if ( item == "0" ) color = "";
                if ( color == "" ) {
                        if ( $0 != "" ) last = color;
                        $0 = "[/COLOR]" $0;
                } else if (color != last) {
                        $0 = "[COLOR=\"" color "\"]" $0;
                        last = color;
                }
        }
        $0 = done $0;
        if ( last != "" ) $0 = $0 "[/COLOR]";
}
{
        if ( NR > 1 ) {
                if ( this == last) sub("\[/COLOR\]$", "", save);
                print save;
        }
        save = $0;
}
END {
        if ( NR > 0 ) print save;
}
```

With the original example:

```
^[[0m^[[38;5;231mV/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 55 to /dev/null
^[[0m^[[38;5;231mV/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
^[[0m^[[38;5;40mI/ggheart ( 1111): onStop
^[[0m^[[38;5;40mI/Test    ( 1111): onStop
^[[0m^[[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): handleBindApplication:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad
^[[0m^[[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
^[[0m^[[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
```

you would get the requested output:

```
[COLOR="DarkSlateGray"]V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 55 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
[COLOR="Green"]I/ggheart ( 1111): onStop
I/Test    ( 1111): onStop
[COLOR="Blue"]D/ActivityThread( 4666): handleBindApplication:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad
D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152[/COLOR]
```

but changing the input to

```
^[[0m^[[38;5;231mV/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 55 to /dev/null
^[[0m^[[38;5;231mV/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
^[[0m^[[38;5;40mI/ggheart ( ^[[38;5;75mI/ggheart 1111^[[0m): onStop
^[[0m^[[38;5;40mI/Test    ( 1111): onStop
^[[0m^[[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): handleBindApplication:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad
^[[0m^[[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
^[[0m^[[38;5;75mD/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
```

gives this result:

```
[COLOR="DarkSlateGray"]V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 55 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  ( 4666): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null[/COLOR]
[COLOR="Green"]I/ggheart ( [COLOR="Blue"]I/ggheart 1111[/COLOR]): onStop
[COLOR="Green"]I/Test    ( 1111): onStop
[COLOR="Blue"]D/ActivityThread( 4666): handleBindApplication:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad
D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
D/ActivityThread( 4666): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152[/COLOR]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds easier with `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  BEGIN{
    %c = (
      "38;5;40" => "Green",
      "38;5;196" => "Red",
      "38;5;75" => "Blue",
      "38;5;166" => "Sienna",
      "38;5;231" => "DarkSlateGray",
      "38;5;40" => "Green",
      "38;5;196" => "Red",
      "38;5;75" => "Blue",
      "38;5;166" => "Sienna",
      "38;5;231" => "DarkSlateGray",
      "0" => "Black");
    $esc = qr{\e\[([\d;]*)m};
  }

  s{$esc(.*?)(?=$|$esc)}{
    $ret = $2;
    if ($2 ne "" && $1 ne $last) {
      $ret = (defined($last) && "[/COLOR]") . "[COLOR=\"$c{$1}\"]$2";
      $last = $1
    }
    $ret
  }gse;

  s{$}{[/COLOR]} if $last'
```

(here taking the lazy approach and loading the whole file in memory.